# TinyMessenger and Monotouch

Tags: ipad, dependency-injection, xamarin.ios, inversion-of-control, eventaggregator

I am trying to use the TinyMessenger in my iPad application. The iPad application has few UIViewControllers. I would like to see the communication among these controllers via TinyMessenger. I understand the steps as

### Step 1 - Create the message hub [ ? ]

```
var messageHub = new TinyMessengerHub();
```

### Step 2 -  Publishing a message [ in UIViewController1]

```
messageHub.Publish(new MyMessage());
```

### Step 3 - Subscribing to a message [in UIViewController2 ]

```
messageHub.Subscribe<MyMessage>((m) => { MessageBox.Show("Message Received!"); });
```

And MyMessage is defined as below

```
public class MyMessage : ITinyMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The sender of the message, or null if not supported by the message  implementation.
    /// </summary>
    public object Sender { get; private set; }
}
```

Please advice if this the correct step to get this setup working. And I dont know where I should create the messagehub. I believe the messagehub has to be global so that it can be accessed by any UIViewController. Can I create messagehub in AppDelegate? If create the messagehub in AppDelegate, how do I access the messagehub from UIViewController1?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this messenger hub in combination with an IoC container.

You need only 1 instance of the hub within your app, and using a container is the way to do this.

See the example from [TinyIoC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/wiki/Setup---getting-started) of setting up the container (which I believe you're using).  You would basically call:

```
var hub = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<ITinyMessengerHub>();
//for subscribers
hub.Subscribe<YourMessage>(OnYourMessage);
//for publishers
hub.Publish(new YourMessage(this, "BOOYAH!"));
```

PS - if you are truly using TinyIoC, there is a `#if TINYMESSENGER` preprocessor directive you can turn on to automatically register a hub for your application.

Comment: thanks for the tips. Where should I declare the line "var hub = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<ITinyMessengerHub>();" in order for me to use the "hub" across the whole application. Sorry if my question sounds silly. I am still learning to understand ipad development framework. Thanks.

Comment: You would do this in any controller or view in which you want to use the hub.  The container handles only keeping one instance throughout your app for you.  That's what IoC or "Inversion of Control" is, a container manages the lifetime and creation of your objects, as well as handling dependencies.  You can make your objects so they are created on a per request basis as well.  See here on IoC: http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2008/02/14/understanding-ioc-container.aspx